# Select random records from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

In table X there's a field Y (int) which holds values from 1 to 8.
I'm trying to find the most efficient way to create a query (which is part of a stored procedure) which can select a random 5 records from the DB.

**The 5 records are not random over the entire table** - for example the procedure should be able
to select 1 random record where Y=1 another 2 records where Y=2 and another 2 records where Y in (4,5,6).

Is there a recommended way to achieve it or should I just use Union?
This query needs to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Are the 5 records you're selecting coming from the table X or some other table?

Comment: The select is only from table X

Comment: Okay, there must be other columns on table X then. I was confused the way it reads it sounds like table X is an 8 row table with just one column, Y. Juergen's answer should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union should be the fastest way to do that

```
(select * from your_table where Y = 1 order by rand() limit 1)
union
(select * from your_table where Y = 2 order by rand() limit 2)
union
(select * from your_table where Y in (4,5,6) order by rand() limit 2)
```